# How do you detect what UIPickerView row has been selected using an if statement

Tags: if-statement, xcode4.2, uipickerview

I have made a button so that when it's pressed by the user and a particular row(s) are selected it does something.
So far I have this:

```
if (pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0) {
                    [mailComposerTwo setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@blah.com",nil]];
                }
```

It works on its own. But when I do the if statement multiple times it crashes.
An ways of making it work?

Any help appreciated, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies with your mail composer, not the picker view. When you show the composer, make sure that you only create it if it hasn't already created.

Also, make sure you release it after you show it:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

...[configure the picker]

[rootContainer presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *finalList = [[NSArray alloc]init];
//put all your if statements
if (pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0)
{
     [finalList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@"email@address.com",@"second@address.com",...];
}
if (pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1)
{
     [finalList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@"another@address.com",@"fourth@address.com",...];
}
//end of if statements
[mailComposerTwo setToRecipients:finalList];
[self presentViewController:yourInitializedMessageController animated:YES completion:^{NSLog(@"message controller is presented");}];
```

This will do a single method call rather than continually reassigning which for some odd reason is causing your exception. `presentModalViewController:animated:` has been deprecated as of iOS 6.0? if not 7.0 I believe.

NOTE! Make the message controller a property of the main view controller. It is good practice so that it is not auto-released by iOS if you need to bring it back up. However if you use MFMessageComposer iOS will keep messenger allocated or running in a thread somewhere so initializing a view controller for it is quick.